# End-User Licence Agreement for TightVNC shows coca-cola logos

Tags: windows-10, license, tightvnc

this has never happened to me before... I downloaded the tightvnc installer for windows from the official website, checked the signature and certificate, and ran it.

Everything was ok, until I got to the end user licence agreement page, where instead of the licence, I was greeted by hundreds of copies of the coca-cola logo:

[image: Things go better with coke]

The weirdest part is that the licence is still there. I can select the text, copy it, and paste it in notepad, and its indeed the GNU licence...

I really have no idea what's going on. My question is, why is this happening? is this a sign that the program has been compromised? is it a joke?

Comment: There are coca cola fonts. Do you have one installed. This looks similar - http://www.free-fonts-ttf.org/true-type-fonts/cocacola-1327-download.htm. Can you copy the license agreement and paste into both Wordpad and Notepad.

Comment: I CAN copy them on both. In notepad its the agreement in english. And in wordpad its the same cocacola words...

Comment: Sounds like a unicode encoding problem.